# Binary Tree Level Order Traversal in Python

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, breadth-first-search

Given the following tree:

[image]

I should return the level order traversal of the tree from left to right:
so the above example would output a list of lists :

> [   [3],   [9,20],   [15,7] ]

I wrote the following code, idea is storing the node value and its depth recursively in a Queue then iterate the Queue tuples and put the in intermediate list O if no more node of same depth append O to output and empty O and so on. However my code Timeout any help?

```
import queue

class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[List[int]]:
        def helper(root,res,level):
            if not root:
                return res
            l=level+1
            res.put((root.val,level))
            helper(root.left,res,l)
            helper(root.right,res,l)

        res=queue.Queue()
        helper(root,res,0)

        d=1
        output=[]
        node,depth=res.get()
        output.append([node])
        while res:
            o=[]
            node,depth=res.get()
            while d ==depth:
                o.append(node)
                node,depth=res.get()
            else:
                d+=1
            output.append(o)    
            
        return output
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code.

Comment: If 9 had 1 or 2 child, could you please give the expected output? Just trying to make sure if it is a proper pre-order tree traversal, or if it is a BFS traversal that you are looking for.

Comment: @san if 9 had a child say "6" the output should be [ [3], [9,20], [6,15,7] ]

Comment: @ElenaGT, okay so it is a BFS. I have just posted the solution below as an answer. If it helps, please feel free to accept it and vote it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my code for the Breadth First Search (BFS) Iterative Implementation with nodes in each level in the final output is under a single list:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution:
    def BFS(self, root) -> int:
        level=1
        current=(root, level)
        s=set()
        result=[]
        Q = [current]
        while Q:
            current=Q.pop()
            level=current[1]
            if current[0] not in s:
                result.append([current[0].val, level])
                s.add(current[0])
            if current[0].left:
                Q.insert(0,(current[0].left, level+1))
            if current[0].right:
                Q.insert(0,(current[0].right, level+1))
        output=[]
        temp=[]
        level=1
        for val in result:
            if val[1]==level:
                temp.append(val[0])
            elif val[1] > level:
                output.append(temp)
                temp=[val[0]]
                level+=1
        output.append(temp)
        return output
```

**Testing:**

```
n1=TreeNode(3)
n2=TreeNode(9)
n3=TreeNode(20)
n4=TreeNode(6)
n5=TreeNode(15)
n6=TreeNode(7)

n1.left=n2
n1.right=n3
n2.left=n4
n3.left=n5
n3.right=n6

sol1=Solution()
print(sol1.BFS(n1))
[[3], [9, 20], [6, 15, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer from [san](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10656054/san). The solution helps me solve problem 107 of leetcode. I revised a little bit based on my understanding. There are two ways to solve this question but I prefer to use BFS fashion. This revised version compresses both **value** and **level** in the queue. It provides more flexibility comparing with only print the **value** of each node in the tree, as other tutorials provided.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def levelOrderBottom(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[List[int]]: 
        
        if root is None:
            return None
        
        level = 1
        q = []
        q.append((root,level)) # push both node and level.
        save = []
        
        while q:
            cur = q.pop(0)
            cur_node = cur[0]
            cur_level = cur[1]
            # print(cur_node.val)
            # print(cur_level)  
            save.append([cur_node.val, cur_level])
            if cur_node.left:
                q.append((cur_node.left, cur_level+1))
            if cur_node.right:
                q.append((cur_node.right, cur_level+1))
                
        print(save) # once print, you will have the idea about how to reorgnized the required output.
        level = 1
        output = []
        temp = []
        for i in range(len(save)):
            cur = save[i]
            #print(cur)
            if cur[1] == level:
                temp.append(cur[0])    
            if cur[1] != level:
                output.insert(0, temp)
                temp = []
                temp.append(cur[0])
                level = level + 1
            if i == len(save)-1:
                    output.insert(0, temp)
            
        return output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below logic , to print out nodes in BFS .
If you also need , you modify the method to return a list as well .

```
def levelOrder(root):
qroot = []
print(root.info,end=' ')
if root.left:
    qroot.append(root.left)
if root.right:
    qroot.append(root.right)

while(qroot):
    tmp = qroot[0]
    if tmp.left:
        qroot.append(tmp.left)
    if tmp.right:
        qroot.append(tmp.right)

    print (tmp.info,end=' ')
    qroot.pop(0)

return
```

Instead of printing the values , you can directly keep appending the value to a new list and return the same .

Comment: Could you clarify if this is meant to solve the OP's original intended task? I found that even after fixing the formatting issues (indentation etc.), this code also gets stuck in an endless loop. I also don't think that it keeps track of the levels in the necessary order as the OP requires. Sorry to point out so much but hope it helps :)